# remove item from json object

Tags: json, nsjsonserialization

i have a json object like this

```
[[{"class":"core.classes.lab.LabOrder","dueDate":1376073000000,"orderCreateDate":1376073000000,"orderCreateUser":1,"orderLastUpdate":1376073000000,"orderLastUpdateUser":1,"orderLocation":"private","orderPriority":2,"orderRemarks":null,"orderStatus":"pending","order_ID":1,"testID":{"LOINCCode":"1234","category":"Blood","class":"core.classes.lab.TestDescription","isSpecimenAvailable":true,"testDescription":"Collect Blood Specimen and get the details ","testID":1,"testName":"Blood Sugar","testProcedure":"Collect Blood"}},{"LOINCCode":"1234","category":"Blood","class":"core.classes.lab.TestDescription","isSpecimenAvailable":true,"testDescription":"Collect Blood Specimen and get the details ","testID":1,"testName":"Blood Sugar","testProcedure":"Collect Blood"}]]
```

and i wanna remove the below part from this json

```
{"LOINCCode":"1234","category":"Blood","class":"core.classes.lab.TestDescription","isSpecimenAvailable":true,"testDescription":"Collect Blood Specimen and get the details ","testID":1,"testName":"Blood Sugar","testProcedure":"Collect Blood"}
```

is there a easy way to do this

Answer (score 1):

var jsonObject = {
  "class": "core.classes.lab.LabOrder",
  "dueDate": 1376073000000,
  "orderCreateDate": 1376073000000,
  "orderCreateUser": 1,
  "orderLastUpdate": 1376073000000,
  "orderLastUpdateUser": 1,
  "orderLocation": "private",
  "orderPriority": 2,
  "orderRemarks": null,
  "orderStatus": "pending",
  "order_ID": 1,
  "testID": {
    "LOINCCode": "1234",
    "category": "Blood",
    "class": "core.classes.lab.TestDescription",
    "isSpecimenAvailable": true,
    "testDescription": "Collect Blood Specimen and get the details ",
    "testID": 1,
    "testName": "Blood Sugar",
    "testProcedure": "Collect Blood"
  }
}

**delete** jsonObject.testID

Comment: i waana remove the item after that not testID

Comment: Exactly, a JSON object is a representation of an object in key-value format. The key for the object you want to remove is `testID`, hence the code above will delete the value associated with that key.